# EF Migrations throwing DataLossException even when there is no existing database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I've enabled EF migrations on my ASP.NET MVC project and have an InitialMigration.cs which represents the base code first model of my project along with the configuration.cs.

I have the following code in my global.asax

```
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<Context, Configuration>());
        using (var context = new Context())
        {
            context.Database.Initialize(true);
        }
```

I have set AllowAutomaticMigrations to 'true' in the Configuration.cs which was generated when I enabled Migrations. Now if I delete my database in localdb and run my project locally the DB gets created successfully with the schema.

However if I run this project on any other machine except the one I used to enable migrations (after I checked these changes in to source control and got latest on another machine for example) I get the following exception on running the project:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.AutomaticDataLossException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: Automatic migration was not applied because it would result in data loss. Set AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed to 'true' on your DbMigrationsConfiguration to allow application of automatic migrations even if they might cause data loss. Alternately, use Update-Database with the '-Force' option, or scaffold an explicit migration.

This does not make sense because on the other machine the DB doesn't even exist. Running the project on machine two was the first time it was run there so there shouldn't be any "data to lose". Am I missing something here?

UPDATE: Also verified the context object at runtime. It is definitely pointing to localdb. So this connection string is correct. The DB doesn't exist yet but I still get this exception.

UPDATE: The initial migration I have is called _v1.cs. If I go ahead and run 'Add-Migration v1' from the Package Manager Console on the second machine where I just got the latest code from it updates the existing _v1.resx file and then everything works correctly. The only thing that changes here is the value of the 'data' node in the *.resx which looks like an encrypted value of some sort.

Comment: Have you checked connection string on other system?Sometime people check-in configuration files and miss to change the connectionstring.Also check if that system already contains DB with same name

Comment: No the second machine is actually my laptop with a fresh install of Windows. It has no existing DB either in a real SQL Server instance or in localdb. Which is why the error is throwing me off. In fact I just installed VS and don't even have SQL Server installed locally.